# How to determine total unused physical memory in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to limit the number of threads I create based on the amount of free physical memory.  For instance I want to stop making new threads once I reach the point that there is only 7GB of real memory left.  How would I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Devices.ComputerInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.aspx) to get the total amount of free physical memory:

```
Dim info = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo()
Dim gb = info.AvailablePhysicalMemory / 1024 / 1024 / 1024
While gb >= 7
    ' start your threads here ... '
    gb = info.AvailablePhysicalMemory / 1024 / 1024 / 1024
End While
```